# Using JQuery Validation on HTML form creating Javascript Table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi so I have the following HTML page and I am trying to get it to validate my form and then run my function to create a multiplication table based on it. I don't really understand what is causing this not to work. Any help would be appreciated :) I am not super good at JQuery, I'm just getting started with using it. I figured that this should validate my code based on the rules I have stated, send out error messages if wrong, and only run my table making function if it works. I have run my table function without the validation and it worked just fine, so that's not the issue

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title> Multiplication Table </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
//$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form[name='tabley-boy']").validate({
    rules: {
      mnrows : {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 49
      },
      mxrows: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -49,
        max: 50
      },
      mncols: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -49,
        max: 50
      },
      mxcols: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -49,
        max: 50
      }
    },
    messages : {
      mnrows: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 49",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 49"
      },
      mxrows: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -49 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -49 and 50"
      },
      mncols: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 49",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 49"
      },
      mxcols: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -49 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -49 and 50"
      }
      },
      submitHandler: function() {
      Table();
      return false;
    }
  });
  }
    function Table()
    {
    var minrows =  parseInt(document.getElementById('mnrows').value);
    var maxrows =  parseInt(document.getElementById('mxrows').value);
    var mincols =  parseInt(document.getElementById('mncols').value);
    var maxcols =  parseInt(document.getElementById('mxcols').value);
    var output='';
    var j=mincols;
    var temp=0;
    var i=0;
    var countm=minrows;
        output=output + "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'> ";

    output = output + "<tr> <td> </td> ";

  //this part creates the column numbers pre multiplication in the black background and styled
    for(temp=mincols;temp<=maxcols;temp++)
    {
         output = output + "<td style='background-color:black; color:white; font-weight: bold;'> " + temp + "</td> ";
    }
       output = output + "</tr> ";


       for(i=minrows;i<=maxrows;i++)
        {
          //this part creates the row numbers pre multiplication in the black background and styled
             output = output + "<tr> <td style='background-color:black; color:white; font-weight: bold;'> " +countm +"</td> ";
           countm++;
           //this next part fills in the rows as it goes by restarting j after each while loope
           while(j<=maxcols)
           {
                 output = output + "<td> " + i*j + "</td> ";
                  j++;
             }
         output = output + "</tr> ";
       j = mincols;
           }

    output = output + "</table> ";
    document.getElementById('cooltable').innerHTML =output;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;"> Multiplication Table Creator!</h1>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-5">
<form name="tabley-boy" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">

<label class="col-sm-2">Minimum for rows: </label>     <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="mnrows" id="mnrows"/></div><br/>
<label class="col-sm-2">Maximum for rows  </label>     <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="mnrows" id="mxrows"/></div><br/>
<label class="col-sm-2">Minimum for columns  </label>     <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="mncols" id="mncols"/></div><br/>
<label class="col-sm-2">Maximum for columns  </label>     <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="mncols" id="mxcols"/></div><br/>
<input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Multiplication Table!" onclick='validate();'/>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-5" id="cooltable">
</div>

</div>
</div>
<!--
 <script>
 //   $( document ).ready(function() {
 //       validate();
//      });
  </script>
  -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you seen any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed a few sections of code and run this in a jsfiddle.

You were missing jQuery

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

I replaced your method validate with document on ready.

I removed the onclick event from your input and used a submit button instead of type="button" as this is just a from with one action.

this:

`<input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Multiplication Table!" onclick='validate();'/>`

to this:

`<input name="generate" type="submit" value="Create Multiplication Table!"/>`

Below is your code with my changes.

````
<head>
<title> Multiplication Table </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form[name='tabley-boy']").validate({
    rules: {
      mnrows : {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -50,
        max: 49
      },
      mxrows: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -49,
        max: 50
      },
      mncols: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -49,
        max: 50
      },
      mxcols: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: -49,
        max: 50
      }
    },
    messages : {
      mnrows: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 49",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 49"
      },
      mxrows: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -49 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -49 and 50"
      },
      mncols: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -50 and 49",
        max: "Your number must be between -50 and 49"
      },
      mxcols: {
        required: "Please enter a number",
        number: "Please enter a number",
        min: "Your number must be between -49 and 50",
        max: "Your number must be between -49 and 50"
      }
      },
      submitHandler: function() {
      Table();
      return false;
    }
  });
}); 
    function Table()
    {
    var minrows =  parseInt(document.getElementById('mnrows').value);
    var maxrows =  parseInt(document.getElementById('mxrows').value);
    var mincols =  parseInt(document.getElementById('mncols').value);
    var maxcols =  parseInt(document.getElementById('mxcols').value);
    var output='';
    var j=mincols;
    var temp=0;
    var i=0;
    var countm=minrows;
        output=output + "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'> ";

    output = output + "<tr> <td> </td> ";

  //this part creates the column numbers pre multiplication in the black background and styled
    for(temp=mincols;temp<=maxcols;temp++)
    {
         output = output + "<td style='background-color:black; color:white; font-weight: bold;'> " + temp + "</td> ";
    }
       output = output + "</tr> ";


       for(i=minrows;i<=maxrows;i++)
        {
          //this part creates the row numbers pre multiplication in the black background and styled
             output = output + "<tr> <td style='background-color:black; color:white; font-weight: bold;'> " +countm +"</td> ";
           countm++;
           //this next part fills in the rows as it goes by restarting j after each while loope
           while(j<=maxcols)
           {
                 output = output + "<td> " + i*j + "</td> ";
                  j++;
             }
         output = output + "</tr> ";
       j = mincols;
           }

    output = output + "</table> ";
    document.getElementById('cooltable').innerHTML =output;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;"> Multiplication Table Creator!</h1>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-5">
<form name="tabley-boy" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">

<label class="col-sm-2">Minimum for rows: </label>     <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="mnrows" id="mnrows"/></div><br/>
<label class="col-sm-2">Maximum for rows  </label>     <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="mnrows" id="mxrows"/></div><br/>
<label class="col-sm-2">Minimum for columns  </label>     <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="mncols" id="mncols"/></div><br/>
<label class="col-sm-2">Maximum for columns  </label>     <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="mncols" id="mxcols"/></div><br/>
<input name="generate" type="submit" value="Create Multiplication Table!"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-5" id="cooltable">
</div>

</div>
</div>
<!--
 <script>
 //   $( document ).ready(function() {
 //       validate();
//      });
  </script>
  -->
</body>
</html>```
````